# ITMS 90433 Error for uploading app: Xcode 12.4

Tags: xcode, ios13

When I submit my app to App Store as TestFlight, my app goes invalid binary. Error message is give as follows:

....

> ITMS-90433: Invalid Swift Support - The file
> libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature.
> Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using
> the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just
> modify the code signature of libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

Would you please recommend any practices for library version checking or others if any, to ensure my app submission contains valid binary ?

Updates :

I need to go to the company and rebuild my iOS app using  Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries -> YES, no issues

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I got exactly the same error today. I don't even use AVFoundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a physical device connected to xcode while building the app solved it on my site. Note: I use `flavors` in my `flutter` project.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project target and then -> Build Settings -> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries and switch to "NO". (this is if you dont use swift in your project).

On the other hand i've seen this more of an issue that has to do with cleaning your project folder.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59830#issuecomment-646603022

Comment: And what if you have a small amount of swift? What's strange is that yesterday's upload didn't have any issue. Only today did I get this problem and I haven't touched build settings.

Comment: This is quite strange that rebuilding my app using Xcode , native Swift project. Very Often, This questions comes to many discussion domain about react-native and flutter

Comment: I’ve found that cleaning my project, erasing the Derived Data folder and closing Xcode completely and then restarting it, sometimes solves these strange react-native issues (most likely flutter also). And it would make total logic sense, because it was working a day before right? And I’m guessing you didn’t make any changes...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the command line tools was not set in Xcode preferences. So in my case I opened:

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations

and set ***Command Line Tools*** field to match the current version of Xcode, in my case

> Xcode 12.4(12D4e)

Then Archive and upload new binary.